# how to write a variable to a

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
import csv

# Note: p1 and p2 are integers
if p1 > p2:
    print ("congratulations player 1, your total bigger so you win")
    print ("PLAYER 1 WINS!")
    f = open("p1scores.txt","w")
    f.write (p1 ",")
    f.close()
    f = open("p1scores.txt","r")
    scorelist = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    for everyrow in scorelist:
        everyrow.sort(reverse=True)
        top5 = everyrow[:5]
        print(top5)
```

The line `f.write (p1 ",")` gives me a syntax error.

I don't know how to fix it,  because I need to write a comma after p1, so I can't just do `f.write(p1)`.

But `f.write(p1)`, too, too doesnt work, it just gives me the error `write() argument must be str, not int`.

How do i get the variable p1 to be written to p1scores.txt with the comma?

Comment: Please do include the full traceback of errors you get. `p1 ","` is not a valid expression, and `p1` looks like it might be a number?

Comment: We also need to know what type of object `p1` is; I suspect it is not a string, for example. Look up string formatting operations if you need to combine `p1` with `,` in a single string, such as `f.write('{},'.format(p1))`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code is hardly minimal, and the argument you give to `write` is not a legal expression.  We don't know what you're trying to do.  Try a tutorial?

Comment: Hi @bigoof, welcome! I disagree with all the harsh comments, don't be discouraged by them. Your question is legitimate, and there's an answer below.

Comment: @MartijnPieters please think before you make these kinds of comments. The question is clearly from someone new to coding, so asking for a traceback or telling them to look up string formatting is counter-productive. This is the kind of thing that turns beginners away from stackoverflow.

Comment: @rje: Yet we have specific requirements here on SO on what makes a question on topic. While I closed the question (it is still lacking the minimal requirements made), I also gave a quick pointer to not leave the question asker without any help. We have thousands of new questions every day, so we have to do what we can in a short span of time. *Especially* when a user is new getting to grips with how SO works will help them get their answers faster.

Comment: @rje: you are welcome to come to either a chat room or to [meta] to discuss how we can better handle questions like these, but I disagree that the comments here are harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate them correctly, the syntax error appears because `p1 ","` is not valid. You're also likely trying to write an integer where as python expects a string. The following code will convert `p1` to a string value and then append a comma with `+ ","`

```
f.write(str(p1) + ",")
```

There are other ways of solving it as well, that might be more optimised/faster, but is often a bit more messy/complex if you're quite new to python.

Example:

```
f.write('{},'.format(p1))
```